# node npm install -g cannot find module config-chain

Tags: node.js, npm

I configured the node plugins on jenkins to install grunt and bower globally.

When i use it on a project npm install is executed:

```
 npm install -g bower@~1.2.8 grunt-cli@~0.1.11
```

Unfortunally it breaks immediately returning the following error:

```
module.js:333
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_0.11.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/npmconf.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

I dont think config-chain is an extra plugin necessary to be installed for it to be there.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit.: Fixed it thanks to the accepted answer:

npm auto-install isnt supported for mac at this time. I had to download the package manually.

Comment: You've posted this as relating to Jenkins and claim in a lower comment you fixed it but did not provide a proper contextual solution. Can you remove Jenkins from the name of the question or amend this question with a full solution?

Comment: @spadict youre right jenkins is wrong there. i also added the solution.

Comment: thanks, I switched to an upvote :) appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`config-chain` is npm dependency, so chances are that your npm installation is broken.

Try to reinstall it, or use one of npm forks if npm itself isn't installable on your system for some reason.

Comment: Youre right it was broken, important thing to mension: npm auto-install isnt supported for mac at this time. I had to download the package manually.

Comment: This question is specific to the Jenkins plugin, which puts its own copies of npm on the machine.  How did you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this suggest, i resolve it.
"Who ever faces this problem, please do a clean install of ionic"

> npm install -g ionic

If it got installed and you're still facing issues, easily install each missing module you face, globally example

> npm install -g config-chain

This will re-install all missing modules, as this might have happened when you upgraded your node
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-find-module-config-chain/37130/7"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a different problem.

It appears as though the [Jenkins NodeJS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) was incorrectly downloading and unpacking packages from the Node.js website. When I went to go look at the unzipped folder and did an `npm list`, there were several packages missing.

I fixed this by telling Jenkins to download a zip file directly and unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

It was the same issue.
I had moved NPM prefix to 'C:\ProgramData\npm\' (you can see your prefix in 'npm config list' command).

After that I should install global packages only under the administrator credentials.